# Вывод кастомного поля при создании записи

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, acf

[image]

При создании новой записи не отображается корректно значение кастомного поля в wordpress, вместо этого выводится [object object], хотя на самих страницах всё как надо. Я так понимаю, дело в чтении JSON. Как это исправить?

Comment: Может вы хотя бы покажете, что передается в эти поля и как они выводятся? А то так это больше похоже на шоу "Интуиция". Причина может быть абсолютно любая

Comment: Полагаю тебе надо почитать документацию по acf. Или как минимум показать код вывода полей.